# In XPath, how do you select all nodes not matching a subset?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm trying to grab a large set of xml nodes all at the same level (whose element names are all different) while excluding a certain subset of nodes. For example:

```
<root>
  <foo>...</>
  <foo>...</>
  <bar>...</>
  <bar>...</>
  <baz>...</>
  <spam>...</>
  <eggs>...</>
  <toast>...</>
</root>
```

so I want an XPath expression to give me the spam eggs and toast node list while excluding the `foo`, `bar` and `baz` nodes. I know the nodes I want to exclude ahead of time but have no clue what nodes will be left over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For well-formed XML,

```
<root>
  <foo/>
  <foo/>
  <bar/>
  <bar/>
  <baz/>
  <spam/>
  <eggs/>
  <toast/>
</root>
```

use this XPath,

```
/root/*[not(self::foo or self::bar or self::baz)]
```

to select all child elements of `root` that are not in the set of `foo`, `bar`, or `baz`

```
<spam/>
<eggs/>
<toast/>
```

as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Combine three Xpathes

```
/root/spam | /root/eggs | /root/toast
```

Or write the same in different way

```
/root/*[contains("spam|eggs|toast", name())]
```

**UPDATE:**

To exclude a set of nodes `spam`, `eggs` and `toast`

```
/root/*[not(contains("spam|eggs|toast", name()))]
```

Comment: spam, eggs, and toast are just an example, there could be hundreds if not thousands of nodes that are all different at this level, I'm just looking to exclude a small subset that repeat a lot

Comment: but could I do:
    /root/*[!contains("foo|bar|baz", name())]
?

Comment: This answer is incorrect; it would also exclude `s`, `p`, `sp`, `spa`, etc elements.  It could be corrected to use string equality rather than containment, but I'd recommend [using the `self::` axis instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38757698/290085)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, the above does work for my current test case, but my test case is very limited right now. I will want to be more explicit so I'll definitely play with both.